# Ansible: How to get task name as a variable?

Tags: variables, ansible

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Hello Sherlock
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ some_registered_output }}"
  
  - name: Hello Avengers
    debug:
      msg: "{{ some_var }}"
```

From the above is there any way in Ansible to get the task name as a variable dynamically,

In example

```ini
var1=Hello Sherlock
var2=Hello Avengers
```

If I can get the name of the task, I can track the status of each task, in example by writing the task name to a file on the fly during execution.

Some one will refer to the file for the task succeeded list and start (`--start-at-task`) the task at the same task where it is failed by giving as input to some Orchestration tool.

Or is there any other way where I can maintain task execution status?

Appreciate help on this.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to set the name of a task from a variable ? Or do you want to get dynamically inside a variable the name of an already existing task in the playbook ? First one is possible with some restrictions, I don't think second one can be done easily, if at all.

Comment: second one, get the name of the task.

Comment: The actual question is "what do you want to **do** with that information?" Because it may be that changing the [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback.html) could accomplish your goal, but we can't say for sure because we don't know what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: if I can get the name of the task, I can track the status of each task. For ex: by writing task name to a file on the fly during execution. Some one will refer the file for the task succeeded list and start(--start-at-task) the task at the same task where it is failed by giving as input to some orchestration tool. or is there any way where I can maintain task execution status?

Answer (score 0):

> ***... writing task name to a file on the fly during execution. Some one will refer the file for the task succeeded list and start (`--start-at-task`) the task at the same task where it is failed by giving as input to some orchestration tool ...***

This is exactly what [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) is doing. If configured under `ansible.cfg` via

```ini
[defaults]
stdout_callback         = yaml
callback_whitelist      = log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Execute shell command
    shell: sleep 0

  - name: Debug task
    debug:
      msg: "Debug output"
```

will result into an `stdout` of

```yaml
PLAY [test.example.com] **********************

TASK [Execute shell command] *****************
changed: [test.example.com]

TASK [Debug task] ****************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Debug output

PLAY RECAP ***********************************
test.example.com           : ok=2    changed=1
```

and a log file `/tmp/ansible/hosts/test.example.com` with content of

```json
Oct 16 2023 19:45:00 - log_plays.yml - Execute shell command - shell - OK - {"module_args": {"creates": null, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "_raw_params": "sleep 0", "removes": null, "argv": null, "warn": false, "chdir": null, "stdin_add_newline": true, "stdin": null}} => {"stderr_lines": [], "changed": true, "end": "2023-10-16 19:45:00.296408", "_ansible_no_log": false, "stdout": "", "cmd": "sleep 0", "rc": 0, "start": "2023-10-16 19:45:00.287217", "stderr": "", "delta": "0:00:00.009191", "stdout_lines": [], "msg": ""}

Oct 16 2023 19:45:00 - log_plays.yml - Debug task - debug - OK - {"msg": "Debug output", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```

which has then all necessary information and which could be parsed by an Orchestration.

**An other Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to get task name as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823257/6771046)