# Ansible: How to get task name as a variable

Tags: ansible

How do I register task name as a variable like this.

```yaml
- name: >>> This is what I want. <<<
  debug: 
    msg: Hello World!
  register: task_name
```

I want to use task name for logging.

Comment: For logging? Are you looking at something like this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html? Could you explain your use case a little bit further?

Comment: I've the same issue. My purpose is to use the task name in a description field within the task.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your tasks names into variables, but I would say that this could go against the readability of the playbook YAML itself.

An example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    debug_name: foo
  
  tasks:
    - name: "{{ debug_name }}"
      debug: 
        msg: Hello world!
      register: debug_register

    - debug:
        msg: "Task named `{{ debug_name }}` resulted in {{ debug_register }}"
```

Gives the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [foo] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Task named `foo` resulted in {'msg': 'Hello world!', 'failed': False, 'changed': False}"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can also access the ***play***, but not the task, name via [`ansible_play_name`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/special_variables.html):

```yaml
- name: Play 01
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    debug_name: foo
  
  tasks:
    - name: This is not the play, it is the task name
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_name }}"
```

Give the recap

```
PLAY [Play 01] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [This is not the play, it is the task name] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Play 01"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***I want to use task name for logging.***

This is exactly what [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) is doing. If configured under `ansible.cfg` via

```ini
[defaults]
stdout_callback         = yaml
callback_whitelist      = log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Execute shell command
    shell: sleep 0

  - name: Debug task
    debug:
      msg: "Debug output"
```

will result into an `stdout` of

```yaml
PLAY [test.example.com] **********************

TASK [Execute shell command] *****************
changed: [test.example.com]

TASK [Debug task] ****************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Debug output

PLAY RECAP ***********************************
test.example.com           : ok=2    changed=1
```

and a log file `/tmp/ansible/hosts/test.example.com` with content of

```json
Oct 16 2023 19:45:00 - log_plays.yml - Execute shell command - shell - OK - {"module_args": {"creates": null, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "_raw_params": "sleep 0", "removes": null, "argv": null, "warn": false, "chdir": null, "stdin_add_newline": true, "stdin": null}} => {"stderr_lines": [], "changed": true, "end": "2023-10-16 19:45:00.296408", "_ansible_no_log": false, "stdout": "", "cmd": "sleep 0", "rc": 0, "start": "2023-10-16 19:45:00.287217", "stderr": "", "delta": "0:00:00.009191", "stdout_lines": [], "msg": ""}

Oct 16 2023 19:45:00 - log_plays.yml - Debug task - debug - OK - {"msg": "Debug output", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to get task name as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304021/6771046)